# Show images in background while using Swiper js in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Swiper js for the carousel in reactjs along with TailwindCSS.
I am building this app landing page where I have this carouse(see image below) and I tried to make same as the design but I am unable to make it using swiperjs.

I want to show it in the design.[see below image].

[image]

but it shows like this [see image below]
[image: behind images are not showing]

here is my JSX code:

```
    import { useEffect } from "react";
import Swiper from "swiper/bundle";
import "swiper/css/bundle";
import img1 from "../assets/Images/slider/1.png";
import img2 from "../assets/Images/slider/2.png";
import img3 from "../assets/Images/slider/3.png";

const Slider = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      loop: true,
      speed: 1000,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
      },
      effect: "coverflow",
      grabCursor: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      spaceBetween: 0,
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 200,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: false,
      },

      // Navigation arrows
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
    });

    // Clean up Swiper instance when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      mySwiper.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  const slides = [
    {
      image: img1,
      price: "$20",
      name: "Special Pizza",
      rating: 4.5,
    },
    {
      image: img2,
      price: "$15",
      name: "Burger",
      rating: 4.2,
    },
    {
      image: img3,
      price: "$25",
      name: "Burger",
      rating: 4.0,
    },
    // Add more slides with random data...
  ];

  return (
    <section id="slider" className="py-8">
      <div className="swiper-container">
        <div className="swiper-wrapper">
          {slides.map((slide, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="swiper-slide flex justify-center" key={index}>
                <img src={slide.image} alt="" />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

custom CSS:

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 750px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.swiper-slide{
  width: 300px;
}
```